# Is there a way to configure VSCode to always open projects in new window?

Tags: visual-studio-code, project, recent-file-list

I am working a lot with `ctrl + R` in order to switch between projects, and I always use 'cmd' to force it to open in a new window (or bring into focus an already opened matched window). This way I never accidentally close active projects.
It's a bit annoying to always use the 'cmd' key when choosing a project to open, is there a way to configure VSCode to use it by default?
[image: open folder]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```json
"window.openFoldersInNewWindow": "on"
```

can be added to [`settings.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations)

> Controls whether folders should open in a new window or replace the last active window. Note that there can still be cases where this setting is ignored (e.g. when using the --new-window or --reuse-window command line option).

Comment: thanks! btw, is it a new feature of vs code or was it always there???

Comment: About [three years ago](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blame/3683dbd1769252265236c0bcead4007785ba1a56/src/vs/workbench/browser/workbench.contribution.ts#L465) at least :)

Answer (score 3):

Got to Settings (Cmd + ,), type "folder" in the search input box, a setting called "Open Folders In New Window" will come up. The "On" option will open projects in new window, keeping the existing project open.

[Settings, folder, Open Folders In New Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWzXl.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to do this, but there are a few workarounds.

One way is to use the Open in New Window extension.

Another way is to use a custom command to open projects in new windows. You can create a custom command like this:

{ "command": "vscode:open-in-new-window", "args": ["${workspaceFolder}"] }

Comment: There is already a correct answer posted, you can do it using ""window.openFoldersInNewWindow": "on"